# How to organize a Coding Dojo?

Tags: learning, testing

Over on stack overflow it was asked how to organize a coding dojo (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338567/how-to-organize-a-coding-dojo-event). I believe that may have been the wrong forum...

I wonder the same thing: how is a Codeing Dojo organized? What is the structure of a meeting? How would one pick Katas? What do you plan ahead of time?

I am interested in any ideas on this as well as links to any resource that may be outlining this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm I think this is what you need to read about [CodingDojo](http://codingdojo.org/). Plus a little imagination on what you consider a coding dojo is. So dont keep only as a structuured practice, following a manual, and more like a day to day experience where you will realize the goal on the go

Comment: Thanks for the link. I missed the obvious. I am not sure, I agree with everything you say: day to day experience is different from deliberate practice and there is value in both.

Comment: Great, most of the time the most simple answer is the correct one but we fail to see it (happens all the time). And about the Dojo experience, as a martial artist and CS student, i find it really exiting. The opportunitie to gather different styles and combine experiences of two unknown persons will result in a really interesting situation. Keep in mind to always make simple clear rules, so everyone can enjoy it! And good luck!